# Vaadin ValueChangeListener on select component doesn't work fine

Tags: vaadin, valuechangelistener

I have a problem with `ValueChangeListener`. I have this code:

```
private void caricaSelectMainUser(){
    Object[] a = socFilName.get(0);
    List<String> elencosoc = societaDao.getSocieta();
    List<String> socUtente = app.getUserDao().getSocietaByUname(app.getCod_utente());   

    for (int i = 0; i < elencosoc.size(); i++) {            
        societa.addItem(elencosoc.get(i));
    }            
    caricaMenuFiliale();
    caricaMenuRisorsa();
    societa.select(socUtente.get(0));   
    filiale.select(a[1]);
    nome.select(a[2]);

    societa.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            filiale.removeAllItems();
            caricaMenuFiliale();
            nome.removeAllItems();
        }   
    });   

    filiale.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            System.out.println("entro nel listener filiale");
            nome.removeAllItems();
            caricaMenuRisorsa();
        }   
    });       

    nome.addListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            getValuesFromDropDown();
        }   
    });       

    getValuesFromDropDown();}
```

This part of code manage the listeners for "società","filiale" and "name".

```
private void caricaMenuFiliale() {
    List<Object[]> elencofilNew = app.getUserDao().getDescFilialeSoc(societa.getValue().toString());
    mapFiliale = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < elencofilNew.size(); i++) {
        Object[] a = elencofilNew.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            mapFiliale.put(a[1].toString(), a[0]);
            filiale.addItem(a[1]);
        }
    }
}

private void caricaMenuRisorsa() {
    List<Object[]> elencoNominativiNew = app.getUserDao().getNominativiFromSoc(societa.getValue().toString());
    map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < elencoNominativiNew.size(); i++) {
        Object[] a = elencoNominativiNew.get(i);
        map.put((String) a[0],a[1]);                        
        nome.addItem((String) a[0].toString());

    }
}

private void getValuesFromDropDown() {
    String codsoc = societa.getValue().toString();
    String codfil = mapFiliale.get(filiale.getValue().toString()).toString();
    String codper = map.get(nome.getValue()).toString();
    String mm = (mese.getValue().toString().length()==1?("0"+mese.getValue().toString())emoticonmese.getValue().toString()));
    String aaaamm = anno.getValue().toString() + mm;
}
```

the sequence flow should be that when "societa" change, select "filiale" is load with data bind with the selected "society" and when "filiale" change "name" is load with data bind with "society" and "filiale" selected. But when I select a new "society", the code below start

```
nome.addListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        getValuesFromDropDown();
    }   
});
```

and I catch the `NullPointerException` on

```
String codfil = mapFiliale.get(filiale.getValue().toString()).toString();
```

in getValuesFromDropDown() method. If I cancel this method call from valueChangeListener from select "nome" all works fine. I know that my logic could have some problems, but I don't know why this behavior. Could anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: in this part of code : String codfil = mapFiliale.get(filiale.getValue().toString()).toString(); the null value field is filiale.getValue().toString()

Comment: No, I mean... What specifically is null.  Use your debugger, figure out what is null.  Post it here.

Comment: "filiale" is null. However, at the moment I freezed the problem using a button. In this way I can handle the different select components avoid the crazy listeners, but I need to solve this problem for my personal knowledges!!!

Comment: So, if filiale is null, that means that it isn't a vaadin issue.  I'm guessing it's a scope issue.  Without the entire file, it'll be impossible to know exactly what is wrong, but it's basic Java debugging, nothing vaadin-specific.

Comment: I don't know how to explain without writing a lot: if you see, there are three listeners (societa,filiale and nome). When societs is selected, filiale is load and when filiale is selected, nome is load. I think the problem is not in vaadin component too, but when application start, the listener "nome" start automatically (this is the cause of my NullPointerException (because filiale is not load yet). If I don't write nome.addListener (in this way there is no listener on component "nome") works all fine!! I'm sure the problem is more foolish than it seems, but I didn't solve the problem yet...

Answer (score 1):

In the societa listener you call nome.removeAllItems(). That will trigger Property.ValueChangeEvent in the nome AbstractSelect.

```
societa.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        filiale.removeAllItems();
        caricaMenuFiliale();
        nome.removeAllItems();
    }   
});
```